# Omission of "when" in relative clauses

Tags: relative-pronouns

One of my students had to fill in the gap (or leave it blank if the relative pronoun can be omitted) in this sentence:

> My landlady says we can't use her sitting-room because we made too
>   much mess the last time ________ she let us have a party.

He wrote "which". The answer key left it blank.

"Which" is not an option, while a blank or "that" or "when" are possible options. But I am having a hard time explaining to him why "when" can be omitted since grammar books seem to claim you can only leave out the relative pronouns "who/which/that".

Please correct me if you find any statements above are wrong.

And my question is: what makes it possible for "when" to be omitted? If possible, quote source for information.

Comment: It's apparently covered in [Next Generation, Student's Book 2 
 by Eoin Higgins {CUP}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dKoaBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%22omission+of+when%22&source=bl&ots=Xedb9jXYp6&sig=Sz5bpjl5JLvjSXudNRfofT2VWQM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAmoVChMIvf6np8TCyAIVAdAaCh1vJA7I#v=onepage&q=%22omission%20of%20when%22&f=false). But you may have to buy it.

Comment: The issue is that it's a defining relative relative clause. That's what makes *that* acceptable and *when* omissible. Notice that the same thing does not apply with *where*  - unless for some reason the antecedent is the word *place*. So we can have *the day (when/that) we last met* and *the same place (that/where) we met last time* but not *the restaurant we met last time*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can generally omit relative pronouns from defining relative clauses if the *wh-* word does not represent the Subject. The word *when* replaces temporal Adjuncts, so if the clause is a defining relative clause we can nearly always remove it.

- That was the day when you asked me to marry you.
- That was the day you asked me to marry you.

One case where this does not seem to apply is with relative clauses using the relative word *where*, although for some strange reason it seems to be marginally acceptable when the antecedent is the word *place*:

- That's the restaurant where we met last time.
- *That's the restaurant we met last time. (ungrammatical)
- That's the same place we met last time.

Comment: Yes, it can only occur modifying _place_. _Why_ is similar, in that it must modify _reason_, or some word with a similar meaning (although I admit I can't think of one just now). _How_ is completely unusable as a relative pronoun; _that_ or Zero must be used -- _the way_ (**how*) _he did it_.

Answer (score 0):

We can leave out "where, when or why"or we can use "that" instead in relative clauses. We cannot leave out " where " and "when " and use "that" in adding or connective clauses.
1.Do you remember the time when (that)we all went to a night club?
2.Can't we go next week,when I won't be so busy?
From Oxford Guide to English Grammar by John Eastwood.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of leaving out "where"?

Comment: Instead of a clause with "where",we can use one with a preposition.The house (that) I used to live IN has been knocked down.